# How do I call a function within an if elif else statement after searching for text in a text file in python

Tags: function, if-statement

Im a total newbie. This is my first post.
I am trying to call a function within an if statement after searching for a string in a text file Its not showing the main function when run.

def menu():
 

    print (Display Kiosk)
    print(1. Buy)
    print(2. Display items)
    print(3. Quit)

def search_string():

    with open(“dataBase.txt”,”r”) as file:
    string1 = SID123456
    string2 = SID654321
    string3 = SID111111

    content = file.read()

    If string1 in content:
        menu()
    elif string2 in content:
        menu()
    elif string3 in content:
        menu()
    else:
        print(“Unauthorised “)
    file.close()

Answer (score 0):

user = input("Enter your student ID :")

def menu():
print("*"*40)
print("     Display Kiosk    ")
print("*"*40)
print("1. Buy")
print("2. Display Items")
print("3. Quit")

```
# from www.pynative.com
```

def search_string():
with open("dataBase.txt", "r") as file:

```
    string1 = "SID654321"
    string2 = "SID123456"
    string3 = "SID111111"

    content = file.read()

    if string1 in content:
        menu()
    elif string2 in content:
        menu()
    elif string3 in content:
        menu()
    else:
        print("Unauthorized")
    file.close()
```